# STM32H7 SPI DMA transfer, always in busy transfer state, HAL_SPI_STATE_BUSY_TX

Tags: c++, c, embedded

I am trying to transfer the data in SPI using DMA, where as my Hal status is HAL_SPI_STATUS_BUSY_TX. The required status is HAL_SPI_STATE_READY. I want to send some bulk data and command(single byte) through SPI. Is it possible to switch between DMA and non DMA mode respectively.  As shown in the image, it loops in the while.
[image]

```
hdma1_tx.Instance                 = DMA1_Stream7;
hdma1_tx.Init.FIFOMode            = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
hdma1_tx.Init.FIFOThreshold       = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
hdma1_tx.Init.MemBurst            = DMA_MBURST_INC4;
hdma1_tx.Init.PeriphBurst         = DMA_PBURST_INC4;
hdma1_tx.Init.Request             = DMA_REQUEST_SPI1_TX;
hdma1_tx.Init.Direction           = DMA_MEMORY_TO_PERIPH;
hdma1_tx.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma1_tx.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma1_tx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma1_tx.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma1_tx.Init.Mode                = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma1_tx.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_LOW;

if(HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma1_tx) != HAL_OK)
{
  // Error
}

/* Associate the initialized DMA handle to the the SPI handle */
__HAL_LINKDMA(hspi, hdmatx, hdma1_tx); 

/* Configure the DMA handler for Transmission process */
hdma_rx.Instance                 = DMA1_Stream1;
hdma_rx.Init.FIFOMode            = DMA_FIFOMODE_DISABLE;
hdma_rx.Init.FIFOThreshold       = DMA_FIFO_THRESHOLD_FULL;
hdma_rx.Init.MemBurst            = DMA_MBURST_INC4;
hdma_rx.Init.PeriphBurst         = DMA_PBURST_INC4;
hdma_rx.Init.Request             = DMA_REQUEST_SPI1_RX;
hdma_rx.Init.Direction           = DMA_PERIPH_TO_MEMORY;
hdma_rx.Init.PeriphInc           = DMA_PINC_DISABLE;
hdma_rx.Init.MemInc              = DMA_MINC_ENABLE;
hdma_rx.Init.PeriphDataAlignment = DMA_PDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_rx.Init.MemDataAlignment    = DMA_MDATAALIGN_BYTE;
hdma_rx.Init.Mode                = DMA_NORMAL;
hdma_rx.Init.Priority            = DMA_PRIORITY_HIGH;

HAL_DMA_Init(&hdma_rx);

/* Associate the initialized DMA handle to the the SPI handle */
__HAL_LINKDMA(hspi, hdmarx, hdma_rx);

/*##-4- Configure the NVIC for DMA #########################################*/ 
/* NVIC configuration for DMA transfer complete interrupt (SPI1_TX) */
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(DMA1_Stream7_IRQn, 1, 1);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(DMA1_Stream7_IRQn); 

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SPI1_IRQn, 1, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(SPI1_IRQn);
```

HAL_STATUS must be HAL_SPI_STATE_READY.

My data length is loaded in NDTR.
[image]

After SPI enabled NDTR = 0x00

[image]

Comment: I had a very similar issue on a different chip (STM32G4); it turned out to be a configuration issue. I'm going to leave a link to EESE answer where I described by issue & the solution in case anyone else finds this question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/606613/194340

Answer (score 2):

I changed the TX DMA stream from DAM1_Stream7 to DMA1_Stream2, It got solved. Do not know root cause why not working at stream7.

Answer (score 1):

One reasone which could cause such problem is that the Variable  which stores data to be sent is placed in the wrong RAM reigon, review you map file and modify linker script

you can find more here
https://community.st.com/s/article/FAQ-DMA-is-not-working-on-STM32H7-devices

Comment: Thank You, Hossam Alzomor. I have configured the dma buffer at >RAM_D2 section. and aligned the data. Even though, the issues remains same. I checked with the DMA registers, S7NDTR (Data register) is 0x0. My stream bit is disabled, hence Data register is at write mode, even then my data is not filled in the register.  In reference manual clearly mentioned, if DATA register is null, then transmission cannot be done.

Comment: May you try to disable cache  if  it's enabled

Comment: Ya I disabled the cache, and my data buffer loading address also RAM_D2. I double checked it.  I don't know why my data register is 0x00.

Comment: I found my NDTR register is loading the number of data to be transfer, when SPI is enabled, NDTR register becomes 0x00. And my status is HAL_DMA_STATE_BUSY, and locks in the loop.